# Why assembly compilation result has big size?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

Visual Studio 2015

I compile simple code, but the compilation result (Release) has 4Kb size. Why does it happen? This is complete code source of my project:

```
ExitProcess PROTO

.data

qword1 qword 12345678ffeeddcch

.code

main proc 
    mov rax, 2c5h
    mov rbx, qword1
    mov rcx, 0
    call ExitProcess
main endp
end
```

Comment: There's other stuff in an EXE beyond the code bytes.

Comment: Is that stuff so big?

Comment: 4096 bytes isn't so big. That's just one disk block (allocation unit), and only one page in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an executable file is compiled, it includes a lot of information it uses for its execution; only a small section of the data in the executable is the actual code.  A good example of this is when an assembly program uses C functions via extern. Here's an article on the subject if you'd like to read more about it: [More info on PE Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

[image: Portable Executable Format]